# When i try to run the below Binary Search code in java, it throws ArrayOutOfExcepetion. Can any anyone have a look and tell me where I went wrong?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, binary-search

It throws error `ArrayIndexOutOfBound`, when i try to search an element which is out of the range of given input array.

Below is the code snippet:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Binary {
    int binSearch(int arr[], int target)
    {
        int low=0;
        int high= arr.length;
        while(low<=high)
        {
            int mid = (low+high)/2;              
            if(arr[mid] == target)
                return mid;             
            if(target>arr[mid])
                low=mid+1;              
            else
                high=mid-1;                         
         }          
         return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        Binary b= new Binary();
        int arr[]= {2, 4, 5, 7, 23, 31, 34, 43, 45};            
        int ans=b.binSearch(arr, 46);           
        if(ans==-1)
            System.out.println("The element is not found");         
        else
            System.out.println("Element is found at postion = " + (ans+1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array length is the total count of elements in the array, but since the index starts from 0, the last value you can access from the array is always `length - 1`, In your code above, you are running the loop from 0 to the length of array, which I believe is the problem here.

So try something like

```
int binSearch(int arr[], int target)
{
    int low=0;
    int high= arr.length -1; //Correct condition

    while(low<=high)   //Correct condition
    {
        int mid = (low+high)/2;

        if(arr[mid] == target)
            return mid;

        if(target>arr[mid])
            low=mid+1;

        else{
            high=mid-1;
          }

    }

    return -1;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you, please take a moment to mark the answer correct (click the tick next to question). Thanks

Comment: Could you please also upvote my question as I am being locked out of asking more question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your setting your `high` larger than your max array index.
Set the initial value to the largest allowed index as the `length - 1`, like this:

```
int binSearch(int arr[], int target)
{
    int low=0;
    int high= arr.length-1;

    while(low<=high)
    {
        int mid = (low+high)/2;

        if(arr[mid] == target)
            return mid;

        if(target>arr[mid])
            low=mid+1;

        else{
            high=mid-1;
            }

    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Please mark the answer as accepted when you have a sec. And have a Merry Christmas.

Comment: Sure. Thanks! +1! Could you please also upvote my question as I am being locked out of asking more question.